# Swift ScoreLabel Xcode 6

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uilabel

I'm trying to get a score label to work in my game, I want the score to increase by 1 whenever "hero" passes a "wall" I've got it so the number 0 is up top in the corner where the score is, and when I start the game it counts up but way too fast. As in the wall won't even be coming yet and I'm already at Example: 67 points. Any suggestions on how I can get it so that when the hero passes the wall it gives 1 point or if the wall gets to point x I get 1 point?

It's kind of like flappy bird!

Here is the code

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


var movingGround: CSMovingGround!
var hero: CSHero!
var cloudGenerator: CSCloudGenerator!
var wallGenerator: CSWallGenerator!
var wall: CSWall!
var scoreLabel = UILabel()
var score = Int()
var isStarted = false

var heroCategory: UInt32 = 1<<1
var wallCategory: UInt32 = 1<<2
var groundCategory: UInt32 = 1<<2
var invisCategory: UInt32 = 1<<1
let walls = CSWall()



override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 159.0/255.0, green: 201.0/255, blue: 244.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    /*
    let backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "background.png")
    let backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture, size: view.frame.size)
    backgroundImage.position = view.center
    addChild(backgroundImage)
    */



    // add ground
    movingGround = CSMovingGround(size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, kCSGroundHeight))
    movingGround.position = CGPointMake(0, view.frame.size.height/2)

    self.addChild(movingGround)

    // add hero
    hero = CSHero()
    hero.position = CGPointMake(70, movingGround.position.y + movingGround.frame.size.height/2 + hero.frame.size.height/2)
    hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: hero.size)
    hero.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    hero.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    hero.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = heroCategory | wallCategory
    hero.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = wallCategory | heroCategory | groundCategory
    self.addChild(hero)
    hero.breathe()


    // add cloud generator
    cloudGenerator = CSCloudGenerator(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: view.frame.size)
    cloudGenerator.position = view.center
    addChild(cloudGenerator)
    cloudGenerator.populate(7)
    cloudGenerator.startGeneratingWithSpawnTime(5)

    // add wall generator

    wallGenerator = CSWallGenerator(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: view.frame.size)
    wallGenerator.position = view.center
    wallGenerator.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect : wallGenerator.frame)
    wallGenerator.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    wallGenerator.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = wallCategory
    wallGenerator.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = wallCategory | heroCategory | invisCategory

    self.addChild(wallGenerator)


    let ground1 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, 20))
    ground1.position = view.center
    ground1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground1.size)
    ground1.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    ground1.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    ground1.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = groundCategory
    ground1.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = groundCategory | heroCategory
    self.addChild(ground1)

    let ground2 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, 20))
    ground2.position = CGPointMake(284, 98)
    ground2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground2.size)
    ground2.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    ground2.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    ground2.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = groundCategory
    ground2.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = groundCategory | heroCategory
    self.addChild(ground2)

    let ground3 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(20, 500))
    ground3.position = CGPointMake(100, 100)
    ground3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground3.size)
    ground3.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    ground3.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ground3.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = invisCategory
    ground3.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = invisCategory | wallCategory
    self.addChild(ground3)

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    scoreLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 20))
    scoreLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.6, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, alpha: 0)
    scoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.view?.addSubview(scoreLabel)


}


func start() {
    isStarted = true
    hero.stop()
    hero.startRunning()
    movingGround.start()

}


override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if !isStarted {
        start()
        score = 0
        scoreLabel.text = "0"
        wallGenerator.startGeneratingWallsEvery(0.5)
    } else {
        hero.flip()
    }


}


func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == invisCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == wallCategory || firstBody.categoryBitMask == wallCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == invisCategory {
        addScore()
    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(heroCategory)) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(wallCategory)) != 0 {
        wallGenerator.removeFromParent()
        let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
        let scene = GameOverScene(size: self.size, won: false)
        self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)
    }


}

func addScore() {
    score++
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
}


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

}
}
```

Code to CSWall (Wall)

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class CSWall: SKSpriteNode {

let WALL_WIDTH: CGFloat = 30.0
let WALL_HEIGHT: CGFloat = 50.0
let WALL_COLOR = UIColor.blackColor()

override init() {
    super.init(texture: nil, color: WALL_COLOR, size: CGSizeMake(WALL_WIDTH, WALL_HEIGHT))
    startMoving()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func startMoving() {
    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-300, y: 0, duration: 1)
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft))
}


}
```

Code that Generates the Wall in game

```
import SpriteKit

class CSWallGenerator: SKSpriteNode {

var generationTimer: NSTimer?

func startGeneratingWallsEvery(seconds: NSTimeInterval) {
    generationTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(seconds, target: self, selector: "generateWall", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


}

func generateWall() {
    var scale: CGFloat
    let rand = arc4random_uniform(2)
    if rand == 0 {
        scale = -1.0
    } else {
        scale = 1.0
    }

    let wall = CSWall()
    wall.position.x = size.width/2 + wall.size.width/2
    wall.position.y = scale * (kCSGroundHeight/2 + wall.size.height/2)
    wall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: wall.size)
    wall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    addChild(wall)

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
everyFrameUpdate() {
  score = ceil((hero.x - firstWall.x) / wallInterval)
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what Pseudocode is/means as I'm new to this stuff! And may I ask where I would put that code? Would I put it in the Update section?

Comment: I've tried to put it in my Update Section but it doesn't work as I get errors!

Comment: Sorry. It's not swift-code. It's just a logic of code. hero.x -- x-position of player, firstWall.x -- x-position of first wall, wallInterval -- distance between neighbour walls.

Comment: Ok, May I ask how I can put that into my code somehow to make it work?

Comment: Edited the code as in fixed it up a little up top :/ getting another problem

Answer (score 0):

I see that in your update call, you create a new wall each time the update() function is called; this seems odd to me.
Also, I think the problem lies in the fact that you're using an SKAction to scroll; I suggest scrolling the objects yourself, checking if it's time to create a new object and then add a new object.

Once an object is out of screen, remove it from it's parent and remove it from the array.

here is what I did (only for me it's from top to bottom).

I have an array property called:

```
var obstacles:[ObstacleClassName]!
```

also, the speed at which the walls should scroll:

```
let obstacleScrollFPS: CGFloat = 150.0 // scroll 150px / sec.
```

Edit: Properties to keep track of the time changes: (I use the timeDifference as a factor for positioning my obstacle, since the update() function won't be called on a fixed interval like every 1/60 of a second. the gameTime is optional: I use this to see how long the current session is playing)

```
var lastTimeInterval: CFTimeInterval = 0
var timeDifference: CFTimeInterval = 0
var gameTime: CFTimeInterval = 0
```

in my update() function, I call scrollObstacles; which checks if an object is off screen and then remove it from the scene and array, something like:

```
func scrollObstacles() {
    for (index, obstacle) in enumerate(obstacles) {
        let offsety:CGFloat = obstacle.position.y - (CGFloat(self.timeDifference) * self.obstacleScrollFPS)
        obstacle.position = CGPoint(x:obstacle.position.x, y:offsety)
        if offsety < 0 - obstacle.size.height {
            obstacle.removeFromParent()
            updateScore()
            obstacles.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }
}


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if self.lastTimeInterval == 0 {
        self.timeDifference = 0
    } else {
        self.timeDifference = currentTime - self.lastTimeInterval
    }
    self.lastTimeInterval = currentTime
    self.gameTime += self.timeDifference
    scrollObstacles()
    if self.isGameStarted == true && isGameOver == false {
        addObstacle()
    }
}


func addObstacle() {
    if self.obstacleInterval > 0 {
        self.obstacleInterval -= self.timeDifference
        return

    }
   ..create your obstacle here, add it to the scene, etc, then...
    obstacles.append(yourObstacle)
}
```

Hope I gave you a push in the right direction, but the bottom line is: Don't use an SKAction to move the wall, since you can't read the objects position then. scroll it manually.

Comment: Yea It helps! :) I'm kind of lost though as I am new to this coding and I keep getting errors like lastTimeInterval isn't a member of the Scene as well as many others up in the commands above like timeInterval , gameTime, Time difference, obstacleInterval

Comment: ah yes, sorry :-) the example was more to give you a general idea instead of a fully working solution (since I was short on time this morning).

Anyway, the properties you are looking for are added to my answer now

Comment: Hey, I have changed the code up a bit! Do you know why It won't seem to up the score to +1 when ground3 contacts with the wall? I tried to use your code buy couldn't get it to work, so instead i have made a long wall right in front of my hero which the invisible wall is called "ground3" and I want the walls that are generating when they collide to add 1 to the score, but it isn't working!